Let $(x-a)^2 +(x-b)^2 =(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$ have three roots then find $|a-b|$.
Let $(x-a)^2 +(x-b)^2 =(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$
have three roots then find $|a-b|$.
My try : I supose that $ r=(x-a)^2$  and $m=(x-b)^2$ now we have
$r+ m=rm $ and $1/m+1/r=1 $ now what ?

Suppose $t$ is a root of $(x-a)^2 + (x-b)^2 = (x-a)^2(x-b)^2$. Let $s = a+b-t$. Then $s-a = b-t$ and $s-b = a-t$, which means $(s-a)^2 = (t-b)^2$ and $(s-b)^2 = (t-a)^2$. Thus $s$ is also a root. Since the original equation has $3$ roots, which is an odd number, there must be a root $x$ satisfying $x = a+b-x \implies x = \dfrac{a+b}{2}$. Plug $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ into the original equation and you will be able to calculate $\lvert a-b \rvert$. (Caution: the answer is not unique!)

Great answer. Can you please tell me why are we taking s=t=x for finding out the third root? If it had four roots, would you have paired the other root with x?

@Gwen The roots of the original equation come in pairs each of which sums up to $a+b$. So in order that the equation have $3$ roots, there must be a root pairing itself.

Plug in the value x = a or x = b in the equation you get:
(a-b)^2= 0 and (b-a)^2=0
which mean a-b=0 and b-a = 0 .
Hence |a-b|=0

for case $a$ apposite $b$ ? Now what?

@amirhosseinbehbodi what do you mean by opposite?

How can you plug in $a$ and $b$? They are not roots!

@Zerox he isn't wrong though. You can plug in values of a or b in x. It never said in the question that x≠a,b. What he found out is a valid value, but your answer gives 2 such values, which are correct I suppose. From your answer, I'm getting $|a-b|=0,2\sqrt2$
